# NameError: name is not defined error in class __init__() method

Tags: python

I'm trying to initialise an instance, but I'm throwing an error every time:

```
import random
class cGen:
    attributes = ['a','b','c']
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = random.choice(attributes)
```

I can import the class just fine, but get an error:

```
>>> c1 = cGen()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\xGen.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.att = random.choice(attributes)
NameError: name 'attributes' is not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If the list is constant, just do `self.att = random.choice(['a','b','c'])`

Comment: @Tomerikoo But then the data will not be inherited to other classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class does not define a new scope; inside `__init__`, an unqualified name that isn't defined locally is looked up in the enclosing scope, which is the scope in which the `class` statement occurs, not the body of the `class` statement.

You'll need to look up the value via either the instance itself, or via the type of the instance.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.att = random.choice(self.attributes)  # or type(self).attributes
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined `attributes` as a class member. Then you have to call it inside the class via `self.attributes`. You can also define attributes inside `__init__` and bind the resulting random choices to `self.att`. But as long as `['a', 'b', 'c']` is fixed (constant), it is also ok doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

`attributes` is defined *inside* the class, so you need to refer to it via the class name:

```
import random
class cGen:
    attributes = ['a','b','c']
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = random.choice(cGen.attributes)
```

Comment: I would recommend using references, i.e. `self` instead of repeating the class name `cGen` as done in the accepted answer. Then you can simply rename the class without paying attention to the duplicated name.